# Sending out a list email through salesforce

Tags: salesforce

How to replace the randomly generated email address from salesforce with my email address in the email coming from Salesforce. Please find the attached screenshot for better understanding.
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps

You can define and manage organization-wide addresses for each user profile. When sending email from Salesforce, users with these profiles can select their own address or the organization-wide address for the email’s From address. Replies are delivered to selected address.

REQUIRED USER PERMISSIONS
USER PERMISSIONS NEEDED

To modify organization-wide addresses:  Modify All Data
Available in: Lightning Experience and Salesforce Classic
Available in: All Editions

From Setup, enter Organization-Wide Addresses in the Quick Find box, then select Organization-Wide Addresses.

**To manage organization-wide addresses, use the available options.**
**To use an organization-wide address, send an email from Salesforce and choose your organization-wide address from the dropdown list.**

Comment: Hi Pankaj,

This will be helpful when raising the case. However, we are sending the mass email blast through "List Email Send" on leads. In my outlook i can see only my email address is coming in from address but in gmail it is adding the randomly generated address like below: Shweta Chadha via owt4ytl7eqx4gyqy.geuo11e.9-ucn4eae.ap15.bnc.salesforce.com I need to show only shwetachadha@gmail.com

Thanks, Shweta